# How do I run a python script that polls for user input on boot?

Tags: python, pi-4, keyboard

I'm reasonably familiar with software, and wanted to help my friend with their cosplay project, which was using [this RGB matrix](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2277) and toggling between different images using [this mini three-key keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09PF417XP). I have a working program, everything works fine. The only problem is that we want the script to automatically run at boot, without a monitor plugged in. I didn't think too much about this during the planning stage because it seemed like it should be something that a raspberry pi is designed for, but we've run into a lot more trouble than I've expected.

Originally, I used the [pynput module](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) to poll for user input, but that seems to have a dependency on X, so we were unable to get it to work without a module plugged in.

I also found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/monitoring-keyboard-without-monitor) which mentions using the `keyboard` module, but I keep getting `raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')` even after installing the module with `sudo pip install`, running the script with `sudo`, even doing `sudo su` to actually change the user to `root` user, so that was a dead end.

Finally, we switched to [sshkeyboard](https://pypi.org/project/sshkeyboard/) which seemed to not have a dependency on anything like that, and the actual code that reads input isn't all that complicated:

```py
import threading
from sshkeyboard import listen_keyboard

def keys(key):
    print("key {key} pressed")
    # Do additional work.

def poll():
    listen_keyboard(
        on_press=keys,
        debug=True
    )

poll_thread = threading.Thread(target=poll)
poll_thread.start()
```

In terms of automatically running on boot, I've considered I think everything that's possible:

- crontab is a no-go because it doesn't seem to work for interactive scripts.
- We were able to start the program by putting it in `.bashrc`, and even tried explicitly redirecting input with `< /dev/tty1`, but in both cases the buttons didn't do anything.
- Same with using `rc.local` -- it has to be run in the background for booting to continue, so getting input to there seems to be a dead end.

The most promising has been systemd with the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Interactive script
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/
StandardInput=ttfy-force
ExecStart=/home/pi/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It's not closer in the sense that the behavior is any different from the other methods, but it *feels* like it should work. I also tried using openvt as described in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106636/unable-to-start-a-script-as-a-service-at-boot-using-openvt-pi-4) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553906/how-do-i-run-an-interactive-script-on-tty1-before-user-log-on), but neither of those seemed to make a difference -- still no input.

The other option I've considered is manually polling `/dev/input` for keypresses (like the `keyboard` module is supposed to do), but that seems like overkill given that seems like something that *should* be a solved problem.

Things are made slightly harder because I'm helping my friend remotely over a discord call, so I can't manually fiddle with things myself. But I'd appreciate any help that people have for how to get a script that runs on boot and can poll for keyboard input.

Comment: A "auto login" and a service starting your program at login should do it? Have you tried that?

Comment: Add to program to the LXDE startup and it will run after you login.

Comment: @MatsK I've been able to get the program running using multiple methods (bashrc, systemd); the issue is having the program successfully recieve keyboard input.

Comment: `I've considered is manually polling /dev/input` ... if that works, then why is that a problem?

Comment: you're doing yourself a dis-service by limiting yourself to Raspberry Pi ... your question is really Linux related ... you may get a faster answer at a Linux site ... ask only about the keyboard, the LED display is irrelevant

Comment: @jsotola I don't have physical access to the raspberry Pi (helping a friend over discord), which makes writing programs like that difficult. I had hoped there might be some Pi-related solution to make things easy (since this seemed like a normal use case for Pi's), but I guess that's not the case.